Using heaviside equivalent in Octave
I'm very new to Octave, but I have a desire to solve Macaulay equations in the program, but a 'heaviside' equivalent function from MATLAB any advice on which package to download.
I have tried to download the specfun package from Octave Forage, but this seems to be an outdated platform and there are errors in that package that prevent its installation.

Welcome to the site! Your question is a bit unclear. Do you need the "normal" version of the heaviside function (double input and output), or the symbolic version? Anyway, the latter seems to be included in Octave's Symbolic Package

'Normal' version  (0= when x<L and 1= when x>L) , sorry if the question was unclear. And thank you for the welcome :)

So can't you define it manually? Something like heav = @(x) (x>0) + .5*(x==0), if you are familiar with anonymous functions (Matlab gives output 0.5 for input 0)

You know, I did not think of that, I simply used Heaviside in MATLAB, but this would solve my issue, thank you so much.

This solved my problem thank you!

Glad I could help! I posted it as an answer so you can mark it as accepted

The numeric (as opposed to symbolic) version of the Heaviside function can easily be defined as follows, using an anonymous function. Note that the definition of the function in Matlab / Octave implies that input 0 gives output 1/2:
heav = @(x) (x>0) + .5*(x==0);

